# compilation behavior for higher order functions with no arguments

Tags: typescript

I have created a higher order function, which should accepts a function of type `(n: number) => string`. However, when I pass in a function of type `() => string`, as below, I do not get a compilation error. why is this?

```
function stringFunction() {
    return "Hello World!";
}

stringFunction(); // returns "Hello World!"

function transformStringFunction(func: (n: number) => string) {
    return function() {
        const returnedString = func(10);
        return returnedString + " Transformed!";
    };
}

// why is this allowed? `stringFunction` has no arguments.
const transformedFunction = transformStringFunction(stringFunction);

transformedFunction(); // returns "Hello World! Transformed!"
```

Comment: Related: [Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)

Comment: It's expected and desirable behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not result in a compilation error because in JavaScript, a function that accepts no parameters just means it doesn't *use* any arguments that are provided.

TypeScript reasonably assumes that a function with fewer parameters than the expected signature simply ignores the extra arguments, so the signature is still compatible since there are no mismatching parameter types and the return type is the same.

A practical example of this convention are the callback functions for methods like [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

If TypeScript were to reject functions that accepted fewer parameters than the callback expects, you would always have to provide a callback that accepted the parameters `index` and `array`, which would be very inconvenient from a developer standpoint.

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
// imagine if this resulted in an error
array.map(n => n * 2)
// and you were required to provide this instead
array.map((n, i, a) => n * 2)
```

Note that these are **not** *optional* parameters, which refer to parameters that may or may not be provided when the function is called. In this case, the parameters are *always* provided, but the function does not necessarily have to use them.

Comment: Also note that changing to `function stringFunction(n: string)` would result in a type error.

Comment: @ExplosionPills That is covered by my statement "the signature is still compatible since there are no mismatching parameter types"

Comment: This is a surprising assumption to me, and undesirable; if I wanted to supply optional arguments, Typescript gives me the ability to do so. It should also give me the ability to explicitly deny any arguments passed into a function.

Comment: @jumbopap optional arguments means that the caller doesn't necessarily _provide_ them. In this case, (and the example I've provided), the caller _always_ provides the arguments, but the function can choose whether or not to use them.

Comment: @jumbopap what is the benefit of denying arguments that will be unused?